# React component is scrolling back to top on re-render

Tags: reactjs

I have this issue with my React component I cannot figure out.  It scrolls back to the top each time it re-renders.  And also, I can't figure out why it is re-rendering in the first place.  Basically I have a grandparent, parent, and grandchild component.  The grandchild has a click event that displays a different child of the grandparent, if that makes any sense.  That click event does a few things, but it is causing a re-render of the grandparent which causes the parent component to scroll to the top.  I will add in my code which will hopefully clear up what I'm saying here.  Just wanted to give some context.

So the main issue is the scrolling to the top.  If we can figure out why it is re-rendering and stop that, that is a bonus.

Grandparent (StaticLine.js):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import StaticOrderColumn from '../ordercolumn/StaticOrderColumn';
import { useGlobalLineTypeActionsContext } from '../../context/GlobalLineTypeContext';
import Details from '../details/DetailsColumn';
import { ModalStyles } from '../modals/ModalStyles';
import {
    useScheduleActionsContext,
    useScheduleContext
} from '../../context/ScheduleContext';
import PalletCount from './PalletCount';
import OrderButtons from './OrderButtons';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
    useGlobalShowDetailsActionsContext,
    useGlobalShowDetailsContext
} from '../../context/GlobalShowDetailsContext';
import { useTraceUpdate } from '../../utils/hooks';

const StaticLine = (props) => {
    useTraceUpdate(props);
    console.log('top of StaticLine');
    const { type, setTitle } = props;

    const { orderType, orders } = useScheduleContext();
    const { setOrders, setOrderType } = useScheduleActionsContext();
    const setGlobalLineType = useGlobalLineTypeActionsContext();
    const showDetails = useGlobalShowDetailsContext();
    const setShowDetails = useGlobalShowDetailsActionsContext();

    const [lineID, setLineID] = useState(-1);
    const [lineTitle, setLineTitle] = useState('');
    const [highlightDest, setHighlightDest] = useState(false);

    const ordersCol = React.useRef();

    let lineCountOffset = 0;
    let numLines = 4;
    let pageTitle = '';
    switch (type) {
        case 'bagline':
            pageTitle += 'Bag Lines';
            break;
        case 'toteline':
            pageTitle += 'Tote Lines';
            lineCountOffset = 10;
            break;
        case 'otherline':
            pageTitle += 'Other Lines';
            numLines = 3;
            lineCountOffset = 4;
            break;
        default:
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setLineID(-1);
    }, [type]);

    const globalLineType = type + 's';
    useEffect(() => {
        setGlobalLineType(globalLineType);
        setTitle(pageTitle);
        const title = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_TITLE ||
            'title'} - ${pageTitle}`;
        document.title = title;
    }, [type, setGlobalLineType, pageTitle, setTitle, globalLineType]);

    const selectLine = (e) => {
        setShowDetails(false);
        setHighlightDest(false);
        const lineNum = e.target.value.substring(4);
        setLineID(parseInt(lineNum, 10));
        setLineTitle(
            orderType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                orderType.slice(1) +
                ' Orders - Line ' +
                parseInt(lineNum, 10)
        );
    };

    const selectOrderType = (e) => {
        const selectedOrderType = e.target.value;
        setOrderType(selectedOrderType);
        setShowDetails(false);
        setLineTitle(
            selectedOrderType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                selectedOrderType.slice(1) +
                ' Orders - Line ' +
                lineID
        );
    };

    const OrderColWithRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <StaticOrderColumn
            {...props}
            title={lineTitle}
            lineID={lineID}
            orders={orders}
            ref={ref}
        />
    ));

    return (
        <div
            className={`staticLines p-1 no-gutters d-flex flex-nowrap${
                orderType === 'completed' ? ' completed' : ''
            }`}
        >
            <div className={'radio-col no-border'}>
                <div className={'radio-container p-2'}>
                    <div className={'radios'}>
                        // lots of irrelevant code here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {lineID > -1 && (
                <>
                    <div
                        className={'col lines no-gutters order-col'}
                    >
                        <OrderColWithRef ref={ordersCol} />
                    </div>
                    <div className={'col row lines no-gutters order-details'}>
                        <Details
                            setOrders={setOrders}
                            orders={orders || []}
                            customStyles={ModalStyles}
                            highlightDest={highlightDest}
                            setHighlightDest={setHighlightDest}
                            errLocation={'top-center'}
                        />
                        {orderType === 'completed' && showDetails && (
                            <OrderButtons
                                setLineID={setLineID}
                                setOrders={setOrders}
                                orders
                                lineNum={lineID}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>

                    <div className={'col lines no-gutters d-flex no-border'}>
                        {orderType === 'scheduled' && (
                            <PalletCount
                                type={'Bag'}
                                lineNum={lineID}
                                orders={orders}
                                setTitle={setTitle}
                                setHighlightDest={setHighlightDest}
                            />
                        )}
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

StaticLine.propTypes = {
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    orders: PropTypes.array,
    setTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default StaticLine;
```

Parent (StaticOrderColumn.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import StaticOrder from '../order/StaticOrder';
import '../../scss/App.scss';
import { useGlobalSpinnerContext } from '../../context/GlobalSpinnerContext';

const StaticOrderColumn = (props) => {
    const { title, lineID, orders } = props;

    const isGlobalSpinnerOn = useGlobalSpinnerContext();

    const sortedOrdersIDs = orders
        .filter((o) => o.lineNum === lineID)
        .sort((a, b) => a.linePosition - b.linePosition)
        .map((o) => o.id);

    return (
        <div id={'line-0'} className={'col order-column'}>
            <header className={'text-center title'}>
                {title}{' '}
                {sortedOrdersIDs.length > 0 && (
                    <span> ({sortedOrdersIDs.length})</span>
                )}
            </header>
            <div className={'orders'}>
                {orders &&
                    sortedOrdersIDs &&
                    sortedOrdersIDs.map((orderID, index) => {
                        const order = orders.find((o) => o.id === orderID);
                        return (
                            <StaticOrder
                                key={orderID}
                                order={order}
                                index={index}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                {!sortedOrdersIDs.length && !isGlobalSpinnerOn && (
                    <h3>There are no orders on this line.</h3>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

StaticOrderColumn.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    lineID: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    orders: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    ref: PropTypes.instanceOf(Element).isRequired
};

export default StaticOrderColumn;
```

This file is where the click event happens and causes the re-render of StaticLine and scroll to top for StaticOrderColumn.
Grandchild (StaticOrder.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import '../../scss/App.scss';
import { getFormattedDate } from '../../utils/utils';
import { useGlobalActiveOrderActionsContext } from '../../context/GlobalActiveOrderContext';
import { useGlobalShowDetailsActionsContext } from '../../context/GlobalShowDetailsContext';
// import { stringTrunc } from '../../utils/utils';

const MyOrder = styled.div`
    background-color: #193df4;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
`;

const devMode = true;
// const devMode = false;

const StaticOrder = (props) => {
    const {
        id,
        item,
        desc,
        cust,
        palletsOrd,
        bagID,
        chemicals,
        totalBagsUsed,
        linePosition,
        palletsRem,
        palletCount,
        requestDate,
        orderNumber,
        comments
    } = props.order;

    const setActiveOrder = useGlobalActiveOrderActionsContext();
    const setShowDetails = useGlobalShowDetailsActionsContext();

    const orderID = id + '';

    // show the details section when user clicks an order
    // THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS HAPPENING, WHEN THE ORDER IS CLICKED,
    // THIS FUNCTION RUNS AND THE StaticLine COMPONENT RE-RENDERS AND THE StaticOrderColumn SCROLLS TO THE TOP
    const showDetails = (orderID) => {
        setActiveOrder(parseInt(orderID, 10));
        setShowDetails(true);
    };

    return (
        <MyOrder
            id={orderNumber}
            className={'order static'}
            onClick={(e) => showDetails(orderID, e)}
        >
            {/*<div className={'orderID'}>{id}</div>*/}
            <p className={'item-number'}>
                {item !== '' ? `Item Number: ${item}` : ''}
            </p>
            <p>{desc !== '' ? `NPK: ${desc}` : ''}</p>
            <p>{cust !== '' ? `Customer: ${cust}` : ''}</p>
            <p>
                {palletsOrd !== '' ? `Pallets Ordered: ${palletsOrd}` : ''}
            </p>
            <p>{bagID !== '' ? `Bag ID: ${bagID}` : ''}</p>
            <p>{chemicals !== '' ? `Chemical : ${chemicals}` : ''}</p>
            <p>
                {requestDate !== ''
                    ? `Request Date: ${getFormattedDate(new Date(requestDate))}`
                    : ''}
            </p>
            {devMode && (
                <>
                    <div className={'id-line-num-pos'}>
                        <p>OrderID: {orderNumber}</p>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
            <div className={'total-bags'}>Total Bags: {totalBagsUsed}</div>
            <div className={'pallets-remaining'}>
                Pallets Left: {palletsRem}
            </div>
            <div className={'pallets-done'}>
                Pallets Done: {palletCount}
            </div>
            <div className={'line-position'}>{linePosition + 1}</div>
            {comments.length > 0 && (
                // bunch of SVG code
            )}
        </MyOrder>
    );
};

StaticOrder.propTypes = {
    order: PropTypes.object,
    id: PropTypes.number,
    index: PropTypes.number,
    title: PropTypes.string,
    orderID: PropTypes.string
};

export default StaticOrder;
```

**Edit:** I'm adding a picture of the problem to help you all visualize it as well.  The order boxes are on the left side of this image.  By default the "Order Details" is hidden.  When an order on the left is clicked, it loads that order into the Order Details and shows that component.  When that happens, that orders column on the left scrolls back to the top.  On subsequent order clicks, it does not scroll to the top.  Only when it shows or hides the "Order Details" does it scroll back to the top.
[image: Orders image]

**Edit 2:** I figured out if I take out the `const showDetails = useGlobalShowDetailsContext();` line and the 2 references to `showDetails` out of StaticLine.js, this issue goes away.  So if that helps anyone figure something out...

**Edit 3:** I'm slowly edging forward.  I figured out how I could remove one of the references to `showDetails` in the `StaticLine.js` file.  Now if someone could help me figure out how to get that last reference out of that component but keep the functionality that would be amazing!!
For a reminder this is the reference I am talking about:

```
{orderType === 'completed' && showDetails && (
  <OrderButtons
    setLineID={setLineID}
    setOrders={setOrders}
    orders
    lineNum={lineID}
  />
)}
```

Let me know if more info or more code is needed.  Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your components with React.memo?

Comment: I haven't, what does that look like?  What does it do?

Comment: I added this to the bottom of my StaticLine component. `const MemoizedStaticLine = React.memo(StaticLine); 
export default MemoizedStaticLine;`  Still scrolls to top.

Comment: @dmikester1 Did you try my solution? Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
const OrderColWithRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <StaticOrderColumn
            {...props}
            title={lineTitle}
            lineID={lineID}
            orders={orders}
            ref={ref}
        />
    ));
```

Move this outside the `StaticLine` as a top level function.

#### What's happening

React is smart enough to avoid recreating html elements and mounting stuff when only parts of the Dom changed. If only a prop changes it will preserve the element and just change its values etc. It is done by comparing the `element.type`.

What you are effectively doing is creating a new `OrderColWithRef` function on each render, since it's a local function, the types are not equal. React will unmount and remount a new html element every time anything in `StaticLine` changes.

Never ever nest component declarations. The only case where declaring a component inside a function would be valid would be a HOC, and even then, the HOC function itself isn't a valid element on its own, only it's return value is.

Hope this clears up things.

Comment: But I don't have access to lineTitle, lineID or orders outside of StaticLine?

Comment: Why not pass them as props to `OrderColWithRef`?

Answer (score 3):

My issue was treating the thing taking in new data as a Component and not as a function that returns a component.

Changing `<NewsList />` to  `{newsList()}` did the trick.

Comment: This worked for me, but I'm not sure why

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Takkie253 I think the reason it's happening is because {newsList()} isn't technically an instance of a react component, so it isn't subject to the same kinds of internal state, including state updates and re-renders. So it's useful when you don't want the contents of a certain components to be re-rendered. But I'm not sure if this is considered best practice (I do it, though).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`? According to the offical [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate):

> is invoked right before the most recently rendered output is committed to e.g. the DOM. It enables your component to capture some information from the DOM (e.g. scroll position) before it is potentially changed.

Basically, the idea is that you can access the current scroll position right before a re-render happens, return in from `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`
and right after the component updates, using [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) you can access the value returned from `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` and set the scroll position to where it was before the re-rendering. Borrowing the example from the official documentation:

```
class ScrollingList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.listRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getSnapshotBeforeUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    // Are we adding new items to the list?
    // Capture the scroll position so we can adjust scroll later.
    if (prevProps.list.length < this.props.list.length) {
      const list = this.listRef.current;
      return list.scrollHeight - list.scrollTop;
    }
    return null;
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    // If we have a snapshot value, we've just added new items.
    // Adjust scroll so these new items don't push the old ones out of view.
    // (snapshot here is the value returned from getSnapshotBeforeUpdate)
    if (snapshot !== null) {
      const list = this.listRef.current;
      list.scrollTop = list.scrollHeight - snapshot;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.listRef}>{/* ...contents... */}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I highly suggest using [@welldone-software/why-did-you-render](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@welldone-software/why-did-you-render) package to give you an insight into why a component renders.

Comment: I did try the why-did-you-render addon actually and didn't see anything useful in the logs.  And since I'm using functional components, I don't think I can use `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

Referencing off of @Mordechai accepted answer.  I pulled out the component that was getting re-rendered but I realized Passing props into that seems like too much work.  What I did instead was just pull out the scroll view instead.

```
{
...
return (
    <>
      <ScrollView>
        <ReviewLayout />
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  );
}


const ScrollView = ({children}: any)=>{
  return(
    <Box style={{width: '100%', height: 500, overflowY: 'scroll'}}>
      {children}
    </Box>
  );
}
```